# Why Clang fails to take default template arguments of template template parameter into account?

Tags: c++, templates

Say we have a following class template:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Container>
class Widget {};
```

Before C++17 you couldn't pass a `std:vector` into `Container` because `std::vector` takes 2 template parameters, not one, even though the second template parameter (allocator) has a default value. So the following wouldn't compile:

```
Widget<int, std::vector> w; //ERROR in C++14
```

Since C++17 default template arguments are considered, so the above should compile. However, I tested it in GCC 7.2.0 and Clang 5.0.0 and while it works in GCC, it fails to compile in Clang with the following message:

```
prog.cc:10:22: error: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
Widget<int, std::vector> w;
                 ^
/opt/wandbox/clang-5.0.0/include/c++/v1/vector:446:1: note: too many template parameters in template template argument
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator /* = allocator<_Tp> */>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:5:22: note: previous template template parameter is here
template<typename T, template<typename> class Container>
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any idea why?

Comment: *"Since C++17 default template arguments are considered"* - They are?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes. See section "Template template arguments" at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters (you can search for parts specific for C++17). Also see CWG 150 at http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4457.html

Comment: @StoryTeller or even better see this defect report: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html (which is the resolution of CWG 150 issue )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48447541/5376789

Comment: @xskxzr that's it, thanks!