# Template template argument mismatch

Tags: c++

The following code

```
#include <cstdint>

template<typename  T>
struct allo{};

template <typename T,  std::size_t a  = alignof(T)>
struct AA{
    constexpr std::size_t align() { return a; }
};

template<template <typename> typename AT>
struct SAR{
};

using UHR = SAR<allo>;

using AHR = SAR<AA>;


int main()
{
    UHR u;
    AHR a;
    return 0;
}
```

is accepted by GCC with `-std=c++17`,  but rejected by GCC with `std=c++14` and  clang (regardless  of  the  C++ dialect).

https://godbolt.org/z/xaE56Y5Pj

Which compiler is right?
Is this  some change in C++17 that clang hasn't  implemented?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before C++17, template template parameters must use `class` instead of `typename`. In C++17, this restriction got lifted and the keywords are equivalent in this context.

Your issue is actually that `AA` has two template parameters and you try to bind it to `AT` which as one. C++17 allowed templates with N non-defaulted parameters to act the same as templates with N parameters in total. But [clang has not implemented it yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48447541/7691729) by default, you can use `-frelaxed-template-template-args` flag as per the answer.

Comment: Drat, my search-fu was not strong enough to find that earlier question.

Comment: Or hide the extra parameter: `template<typename T> using AAT = AA<T>; using AHR = SAR<AAT>;`

Comment: is it only "templates with N non-defaulted parameters to act the same as templates with N parameters in total" or can a template with 1 non-default and 3 defaults also act like one with 2 parameters total?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I believe the latter should be the case, e.g. if `type<X,Y,Z> x;` is valid, it should pass as a template template parameter with 3 parameters. My wording was not entirely correct then.