# GCC/Clang disagreement: Does <typename...> match <typename> in C++17 template template substitution?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following sample code, compiled in C++17 mode:

```
template <typename...>
struct Bar{};

template <typename T, template <typename> typename C> 
struct Foo {
    int x;
    C<T> test_;
};

int main() {
    Foo<int, Bar> test;
    test.x = 5;
    return test.x;
}
```

Every version of GCC from 7.x all the way to 11 (HEAD) will [happily compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5bxEtebH7BZydryR) it and the executable will return the expected value, as long as the language standard is set to C++17.

Clang, on the other hand, [disagrees](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GWYcJ17M7uXUwgaC) across every version I've tried:

```
prog.cc:11:14: error: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
    Foo<int, Bar> test;
             ^
prog.cc:1:22: note: template type parameter pack does not match template type parameter in template argument
template <typename...>
                     ^
prog.cc:4:41: note: previous template type parameter declared here
template <typename T, template <typename> typename C> 
                                        ^
1 error generated.
```

Interestingly enough, this is basically the same error that GCC [outputs](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2YaVzwgukkLLObyg) when in C++14 (or older) mode:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:11:17: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class T, template<class> class C> struct Foo'
   11 |     Foo<int, Bar> test;
      |                 ^
prog.cc:11:17: note:   expected a template of type 'template<class> class C', got 'template<class ...> struct Bar'
prog.cc:12:10: error: request for member 'x' in 'test', which is of non-class type 'int'
   12 |     test.x = 5;
      |          ^
prog.cc:13:17: error: request for member 'x' in 'test', which is of non-class type 'int'
   13 |     return test.x;
      |                 ^
```

If my understanding of template parameters from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) is correct, then C++17 no longer requires an exact match for the parameter list, but it is unclear to me how that affects parameter packs.

Which compiler is correct here? And is there a way to convince Clang to work for code like this?

---

**Update:** [HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) suggested using the `-frelaxed-template-template-args` Clang option, which indeed makes Clang behave similarly to GCC. From the Clang `--help` output:

```
-frelaxed-template-template-args
                        Enable C++17 relaxed template template argument matching
```

I suppose I should have found that before posting; my only excuse is that the Clang manual pages are not up to GCC standards on my system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293162/how-is-p0522r0-breaking-code TL;DR: Clang is wrong, intentionally. Use `-frelaxed-template-template-args` to make it behave.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Yes, that option seems to do the trick; now I only have about a hundred other errors to address :-)