# C++ function for container

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a C++ function like:

```
template <T<int> >
void printIntegers(T<int> ints) {
    for (int i: ints) printf("%d ", i);
}
```

Because I want `T<int>` to be either `vector<int>` or `list<int>` or any other STL container. How should I write the template parameter?

Comment: it should only accept containers of `int` ?

Comment: You would have to write a template template parameter. That said, it would be simpler to simply have a template type argument for what is passed directly.

Comment: why dont you define ***vec<T>*** instead ***T<int>*** as parameter

Comment: If you'd use `std::cout <<` instead of `printf`, this problem would be gone (unless printing is just an example).

Comment: Why not call it `prints`?

Comment: @super Because that's a terribly non-descriptive name?

Comment: prints rhymes with ints :), and contains ints

Comment: Your function names are not the place for obscure jokes that have to be explained

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings What's the point if there is no fun lol?

Comment: @super If you're having fun at the fatal expense of maintainability, you're sacrificing professionalism and practicality for your "fun" and thereby doing it wrong. Have fun after work.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm just joking!

Comment: @super And see how that wasted both our time during the working day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't overthink it.

```
template <typename Container>
void printIntegers(const Container& container)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Container::value_type, int>);
    
    for (const auto& el : container)
    {
       printf("%d ", el);
    }
}
```

Or even just:

```
template <typename Container>
void printThings(const Container& container)
{
    for (const auto& el : container)
    {
       std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a reference to int from the container... Compiler will optimize that indirection out, ok, but it did not help here for anything I believe.

Comment: @Klaus *shrug* Don't copy things for no reason. Okay, in the first example, when we _know_ it's an `int`, perhaps just use `const auto`, but you're not passing it to a function so there's no overhead. I like to always write `const auto&` because why not. It describes precisely to the compiler what you want the program to mean.

Comment: I am with you to not copy anything. But for an int the overhead to take a "pointer" internally and dereference it later is uneeded overhead. Quite clear the compiler knows it and did not what you suggest :-) But it is still not needed if the type is known to be int. Only as a remark. Everything is fine for real world optimzing compilers :-)

Comment: @Klaus There is no such overhead. No compiler will do that. It's not even what the semantics describe. `el` is just an alias, not a pointer. (You're thinking of function arguments where said references must be implemented by pointers.)

Comment: Surprisingly simple but effective solution!

Answer (score 4):

You could take a template template parameter as the argument:

```cpp
template <template <typename...> typename Container>
void printIntegers(Container<int> ints) {
  for (int i : ints) std::printf("%d ", i);
}
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter

As other answers have already suggested, though, taking by const reference may be preferable, and there are probably betters ways of doing your example anyway.

Comment: why the ... after typename? I don't see any guidance in the cppreference webpage. Anyway, I see that without them, the code won't compile.

Comment: Technically you don't need them for recent C++ standards, but some compilers (notably Clang) otherwise don't or didn't compile this. The quick reason is that `std::vector` and most other standard containers actually have (at least) two template parameters, `T` and (defaulted) `Alloc`, so we instead make it a variadic template in the template parameter to match as many types as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You simply use a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) ( *template template parameter* subsection there ) like this:

```
template < template < typename > typename T > void printIntegers( T<int>& container ) 
{
    for ( int el: container ) { std::cout << el << " " ; } 
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> i{1,2,3,4};
    std::list<int> l{7,8,9,10};

    printIntegers( i );
    printIntegers( l );
}
```

Some hints: In your code you did a copy instead of a reference by passing the container into your function. That will generate a lot of overhead by copying the content. The compiler may optimze it out, but you should write it with a reference to get a guarantee to not waste your memory with a copy.

Comment: Clang refuses to compile this (incorrectly, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293162/how-is-p0522r0-breaking-code)), but `template <typename...> template T` does work. Also, this way it doesn't seem to require C++17.

Comment: Note that this requires C++17 standard.

Comment: @eerorika: We have 2020, so I can assume that people are "already" using the last standard :-) Question was tagged c++ so I believe we can also use c++20 here.

Comment: I wish we had not only C++20, but C++20 compilers as well

Comment: @eerorika: gcc 10 has already some features and some of them are working :-) You are right, wrote some bug report last days, but hey, the future starts now!

Comment: _"We have 2020, so I can assume that people are "already" using the last standard :-)"_ You really can't

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: If the author of a question wants to restrict the answer to some standard, he should tag also with the standard he wants. If we see c++ as the only tag, we can assume current standard! But my answer is fine with C++17 and that hopefully we all can expect :-)

Comment: To be fair, although finalised, C++20 isn't even published yet, so it's not _really_ the latest standard :)

Comment: @Klaus The latest standard is C++17, and in practice many, many people can not use such cutting edge things yet (think Enterprise). That's just a fact of life. So, no, you cannot assume. Though the tagging _should_ indicate older (pre-C++17) standards, yes.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I am absolutely with you. But as long as a question is not tagged with a given standard, there is no need to restrict it to some older standard. Simply that. I know some people using still boarland compilers for education... all known!