# How to pass the name of a template class to a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I know we can do the following,

```
template <class CONTAINER>
void f(CONTAINER *c){}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    f(&v);
    std::set<int> s;
    f(&s);
}
```

Then, I want an alternative (convenient for my project), like the following,

```
template <class CONTAINER>
void f(CONTAINER<int> *c){} // the CONTAINER is the name of a template class
```

But, the compiler outputs

```
error: ‘CONTAINER’ is not a template
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It's called [template template paramer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter)

Comment: ^^^ Coupled with variadic template arguments it can be quite elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter):

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template<template<typename> typename CONTAINER>
void f(CONTAINER<int> *){}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    f(&v);
    std::set<int> s;
    f(&s);
}
```

*"Matching template template parameters to compatible arguments"* is a C++17 feature. This won't work with C++14 because `std::vector` has more than one template parameter.

You need `-frelaxed-template-template-args` to compile this code with Clang, see: [Template template parameter in function templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884147/template-template-parameter-in-function-templates) and [How is P0522R0 breaking code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293162/how-is-p0522r0-breaking-code)

An alternative way is to use template template parameters with variadic templates to avoid *"Matching template template parameters to compatible arguments"*:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template<class T, template<class, class...> class CONTAINER, class... Args>
void f(CONTAINER<T, Args...> *){}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    f(&v);
    std::set<int> s;
    f(&s);
}
```

or

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template<template<class, class...> class CONTAINER, class... Args>
void f(CONTAINER<int, Args...> *){}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    f(&v);
    std::set<int> s;
    f(&s);
}
```

This works with C++11.

Comment: You may want to actually try compiling that.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried before I posted: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9vMIp3jRzDentnde There is different behavior between GCC and Clang: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884147/template-template-parameter-in-function-templates and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293162/how-is-p0522r0-breaking-code

Comment: yeah, I use clang and -std=c++14, so this pukes on multiple fronts. `typename` isn't allowed before CONTAINER, but `class` is, and as you said, partial matches to classes with additional default arguments wont' work either (but variadic argument specs will fix that too).

Comment: @WhozCraig No problem with Clang and `-frelaxed-template-template-args`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/GkP7R4Wa1hLI8wwn But _"Matching template template parameters to compatible arguments"_ is a C++17 feature. This won't work with C++14

Comment: Yeah, I just use `template < class T, template <class, class...> class CONTAINER, class... Args> void f(CONTAINER<T, Args...> *){}` as it works on everything since C++11 with no additional flags.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're open to give an alternative answer. IMHO my answer fits better to the question and I encountered one use case for this in 16 years. But probably your answer is better because it's more general. I don't want to interpret OP's question and I'm not sure if `std::vector<float> v;` should also use `CONTAINER<int> *`

Comment: Nah. what you have works for me. I honestly didn't even know this was addressed in 17. I sort of stopped paying attention to the standard updates after 14, paid to engineer and all. Learned something, so thanks!.

Comment: +1, However - out of curiosity -  can't the latter (C++11) version preserve the constraint about `<int>` template as in the original op's assumption?